# Overload resolution failed when attempting to display messagebox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, messagebox

I'm having an issue writing in VB 2010 with the following code.

```
 Public Sub about(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Omega Management System © Shelby Taylor 2013 ******@gmail.com", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Sub
```

I have this code in a module that I'm using as a general purpose 'holder' to hold some database connections behind the scenes of my program. I would like to make a messagebox subprocedure which will display my contact information should the user click a button, in which case I will call upon this procedure and display the messagebox.

I am receiving the following error.

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Show' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
'Public Shared Function Show(owner As System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, text As String, caption As String) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'owner' narrows from 'String' to 'System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window'.
'Public Shared Function Show(owner As System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, text As String, caption As String) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'text' narrows from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' to 'String'.
'Public Shared Function Show(owner As System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, text As String, caption As String) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'caption' narrows from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon' to 'String'.
'Public Shared Function Show(text As String, caption As String, buttons As System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'caption' narrows from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' to 'String'.
'Public Shared Function Show(text As String, caption As String, buttons As System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'buttons' narrows from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons'. M:\oms\omega_managment_system\WindowsApplication1\globalStructures.vb   21  9   Omega Managment System
```

And I don't understand what is happening. Could someone please explain what the issue is, and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells all:

```
Public Shared Function Show(text As String, caption As String, _
buttons As System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons) ...
Argument matching parameter 'caption' narrows from 
  'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' to 'String'.
```

You have to follow those formats.  The second arg should be a string (the caption) but you are passing the button info.  There are multiple ways it can be called (so the multiple msgs) but you need to follow one of them